# Word VBA hanging indent multiple differently indented paragraphs, without moving paras

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, indent

I am trying to write a macro to apply hanging indents to all paragraphs in a selection, relative to the first line.

The macro needs to work on multiple different paragraphs, including un-numbered ones, and ListNum paragraphs at different levels with different indentations.

`Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabHangingIndent 1` only works when paragraphs of the same type are selected.

If the selection contains different paragraph indentations, the indentation of *all* paragraphs in the selection is changed to the same as the paragraph at the top of the selection.

Is there a way to indent the lines below the first lines without moving the paragraph positions?

I could not find the answer on the net.

Sample selection (the yellow lines should be indented):
[image: Sample selection]

Result on mixed selection:
[image: Result on mixed selection]

Comment: There is a big difference in how indents are applied between numbered and unnumbered paragraphs if your numbering is automatic. This is a difference in the word object model.

Comment: If you have code you are already using, you might want to post this in the Stack Overflow forum.

Comment: @Charles Kenyon I am honoured by your suggestion.  Unfortunately I have been blocked from posting in Stack Overflow, I have no idea why, and have been unable to find out.  If you could help with that, I would be very grateful! V

Comment: (1) Your text in the Answer should be in your question unless it actually solves your problem. (2) I am a neophyte here and have no idea why you would be blocked in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out - the following adds hanging indents to mixed para types where `TabHangingIndent` loses the para indents. (Except for paras in tables, which 3. doesn't work on.)

```
Sub HangingIndentMIXEDParaTypes_KeepsOriginalParaPositions()
'use where TabHangingIndent loses paragraphs position
    '1.===== CHANGE DEFAULT TAB STOPS TO DESIRED HANGING INDENT SIZE
        ActiveDocument.DefaultTabStop = CentimetersToPoints(0.75)
    
    '2.===== "hanging para" = unindent all 1st lines! (Paragraph dialog box)
        Selection.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = CentimetersToPoints(-0.75)

    '3.===== indent whole paras moves 1st lines to original positions, keeps hanging indents :)
        Selection.Paragraphs.INDENT
        
    '4.===== RESTORE DEFAULT PARA STOPS
        ActiveDocument.DefaultTabStop = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    
    End Sub
```